# HM-10 BLE Module - connect to other Devices

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

first of all: What i am trying to do is only for private interest.

I'd like to connect a AT-09/HM-10 BLE-Module with Firmware 6.01 to another device which provides also a BLE Module, which it is not based on the CC254X-Chip,

I am able to communicate with this Device using my Laptop with integrated Bluetooth, Linux and the bluepy-helper. I am also able to make a connection using the HM10 through a USB-RS232-Module and "Hterm", but after that quite Stuck in my progress.

By "reverse-engineering" the Android-Application for controlling this particular device i found a set of Commands, stored as Strings in Hex-Format. The Java-Application itself sends out the particular Command combined with a CRC16-Modbus-Value in addition with a Request (whatever it is), to a particular Service and Characteristic UUID.

I also have a Wireshark-Protocol pulled from my Android-Phone while the application was connected to the particular device, but i am unable to find the commands extracted from the .apk in this protocol.

This is where i get stuck. After making a connection and sending out the Command+CRC16-Value i get no response at all, so i am thinking that my intentions are wrong. I am also not quite sure how the HM-10-Firmware handles / maps the Service and Char-UUIDs from the destination device.

Are there probably any special AT-Commands which would fit my need?

I am absolutely not into the technical depths of Bluetooth and its communication layer at all. The only thing i know is that the HM-10 connects to a selected BLE-Device and after that it provides a Serial I/O and data flows between the endpoints.

I have no clue how and if it can handle Data flow to certain Service/Char UUIDs from the destination endpoint, althrough it seems to have built-in the GATT , l2cap-Services and so on. Surely it handles all the neccessary communication by itself, but i don´t know where i get access to the "front-end" at all.

Best regards !

Comment: When you say you can communicate with the device using your notebook, does this already include writing the Command+CRC16 value?

Comment: Nope. The communication vida the Notebook to this device is handled entirely by the bluepy-helper. It provides a shell input and various commands to get access to the particular device. I can there display the service and characterisic UUIDs of the connected  device, also read and write from/to various adresses, which are assigned to the UUIDs.

Comment: Many thanks, but that is not my approach. The HM-10 should connect to a BLE-Device and use -its- characteristics, not the other way around. That is where i am stuck. But unfortunaly, it seems that (in this Case) my AT-09 (2541) is being somehow bricked by uploading another Firmware. I can repeditly perform it, but it won´t respond any longer to AT-Command,s no matter, which Baudrate, CR/LF and so on i am using.